# Can you have the compiler check the names of variables and cause build errors on certain names?

Tags: naming-conventions, compile-time

I honestly can't even find anything like this anywhere on the internet, seems kind of like an obvious feature that is missing.

Basically, I'd like the compiler to check the names of every local variable and cause a build to fail if certain variable names are used.  Just as an example, I'd like the build to fail if someone tries to use "x" as a variable for anything.

I get that determined folks would find a ways around it, but I'd like to see if it could be done.

I'm interested more in hearing if this can be done in Visual Studio since that's just what I use the most, but I'd be interesting in hearing about any kind of feature like this for any language / compiler if you know of one.

Comment: that's not a language feature, but a coding style; look for static analysis tools (like sonar or checkstyle)

Comment: This is trivial in Smalltalk because the Smalltalk compiler is right there, written in Smalltalk.